# Шаблон shared_ptr<int[]>

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Как сделать чтобы у моего класса можно было использовать шаблон с [], чтобы сказать ему что у нас массив объектов T?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061979/shared-ptr-to-an-array-should-it-be-used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы шаблон мог принимать такой тип, никаких специальных действий не требуется.

Если вам надо как-то понять, что вы получили такой тип (массив без размера), или делайте специализацию, или используйте [`std::is_unbounded_array_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_unbounded_array) + [`std::remove_extent_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_extent).

Comment: Ага, в итоге что-то похожее вышло:
Прилагаю ссылку на реализацию:
https://github.com/VladislavHacker/CppExamples/blob/main/smart_pointers/pointers.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Я разобрался со своим вопросом. Реализация:
https://github.com/VladislavHacker/CppExamples/blob/main/smart_pointers/pointers.cpp

Comment: Что это такое? `if (&other != *this) `

Comment: проверка на самокопирование, проверяем по адресу объекта в памяти, и если видим что это один и тот же объект то копировать ничего не будем. Тут должно быть вот так &other != this

Comment: В том то и дело что должно :) но в улде по ссылке не так.

Comment: угу, в спешке писал